# How to test Devise Login page with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I'm really annoying this problem about this.

Error is like this.
Despite of declaration of TestLoginController, I always trapped same error.
What should I do?

```
$ bin/rspec
Running via Spring preloader in process 18113
/Users/noriakitakamizawa/dola/spec/controller/test_login_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant TestLoginController (NameError)
    from /Users/noriakitakamizawa/dola/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/noriakitakamizawa/dola/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `each'
    from /Users/noriakitakamizawa/dola/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `load_spec_files'
```

Here's the code.

spec/controller/test_login_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe TestLoginController do
  login_admin

  it "should have a current_user" do
    # note the fact that you should remove the "validate_session" parameter if this was a scaffold-generated controller
    expect(subject.current_user).to_not eq(nil)
  end

  it "should get index" do
    # Note, rails 3.x scaffolding may add lines like get :index, {}, valid_session
    # the valid_session overrides the devise login. Remove the valid_session from your specs
    get 'index'
    response.should be_success
  end
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'devise'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

And here's another helper.

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)

require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'devise'
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  # for Devise
  #config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  #config.include Capybara::DSL
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
```

Comment: your file name should be `test_login_controller_spec.rb` instead of `test_login_spec.rb`.

Comment: Even though I fixed filename, it's still same...

Comment: Make sure `rspec` is recognizing your test as a `controller` test.  You may have the default set to identify tests by their location in the `spec/` directory, but try changing the first line to: `describe TestLoginController, type: :controller do` just in case.